# How to make a grouped barchart with a second y-axis (line graph)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to make a bar chart showing chronological and cognitive age for each age decade and a second y-axis on the right which depicts the difference as a line graph as percentage (called "Delta").
Hope you can help me.

I tried the following, but I do not know how to assign "Delta" as second y-axis.

```
dput(comparison_age)
structure(list(Mean = structure(1:7, .Label = c("20s", "30s", 
"40s", "50s", "60s", "70s", "80s"), class = "factor"), Chronologic = c(24.7, 
34, 45.2, 55.1, 64.8, 74.6, 81.5), Cognitive = c(27.2, 32.7, 
42.5, 49.1, 57, 68.4, 73.6), Delta = structure(c(7L, 4L, 5L, 
2L, 3L, 6L, 1L), .Label = c("-10%", "-11%", "-12%", "-4%", "-6%", 
"-8%", "10%"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

```
dput(comparison_age)
df <- data.frame(Mean, Chronologic, Cognitive, Delta)
barplot(comparison_age, x= "Mean", y="Chronologic", beside=T)

require(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
df.long <- gather(df, variable, value, -Mean)
ggplot(data = df.long, aes(x = Mean, y = value, fill = variable)) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge())
```

[image: This is how it looks right now]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

great reproducible code!

I would start by converting your `df.long$value` column to a numerical value as factors are tricky to plot as if they were continuous. You can do this by substituting `%` to empty strings and converting to numeric.

```
df.long$value <- as.numeric(gsub("%", "", df.long$value))
```

Then, we can plot a secondary axis using the `sec.axis` argument in `scale_y_continuous()`. Also we need to separate out what we want to plot as bars from what we want to plot as lines using the `data` argument in the geoms. Furthermore, I added +20 to the delta, and substract -20 from the secundary axis to get into a more similar range to the first axis, as the second axis is simply a transformation of the first.

```
ggplot(data = df.long, aes(x = Mean, y = value)) +
  geom_col(data = df.long[df.long$variable != "Delta" ,], position = position_dodge(),
           aes(fill = variable)) +
  geom_line(data = df.long[df.long$variable == "Delta",], 
            aes(group = 1, y = value + 20)) +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(trans = ~.- 20, name = "Delta"))
```

Which gave me this plot:

[image]

Hope that helped!

Comment: Awesome! That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much!